# grails composite ID does not work

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain class:

```
class AccountSupplier implements Serializable {

    static mapping = {
       table 'MY_TABLE'
       version false

       accountReference /*indexColumn: 'ACNTID', */ column:'REFACNTID'
       supplierReference /* indexColumn:'SUPID' ,*/ column:'REFSUPID'

       id composite:['accountReference', 'supplierReference']
    }

   Account accountReference
   Supplier supplierReference
}
```

everything works fine with this except the ID handling. When I try to get the ID of an AccountSupplier Object, i dont get anything. The effect is that i am not able to delete or edit something. Only listing does work (without ID)

how can i handle the ID for getting, deleting ...

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual ID.  That's not really how composite ID's work.  You'll need to provide a method on your class to allow for deleting (as well as other things)

```
static boolean remove(Account accountReference, Supplier supplierReference, boolean flush = false) {
  AccountSupplier instance = AccountSupplier.findByAccountAndSupplier(accountReference, supplierReference)
  instance ? instance.delete(flush: flush) : false
}
```

Comment: yes, i thougt about this. But why do i have to implement it by myself? What is the reason for a composite ID then? It should do this by generating keys on the fly by combining the two keys...

Comment: keys generated?  Yes.  One ID that you can use to perform actions?  Nope.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid

"Unfortunately, this approach means that a persistent object is its own identifier. There is no convenient "handle" other than the object itself."